# Responsive Table Break

Tags: html, css

I have a website that is connected to a database. The website has a table that pulls out the values from the database. I want this table to be responsive. I have almost got it to work except one part. Everything is showing and working except for the titles(Band Name, City, Role, Style, SKill). They wont show. I think it has something to do with the last CSS code (content attribute). If someone has experience or can help out, I would highly appreciate it! Take a look at the photo to to see what I mean

[screenshot from problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srGzt.png)

```css
.table td,
.table th {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  .table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  .table,
  .table tbody,
  .table tr,
  .table td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .table tr {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .table td {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
  }
  .table th::before {
    content: attr(scope);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="band-finder-table">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Band Name</th>
        <th scope="col">City</th>
        <th scope="col">Role</th>
        <th scope="col">Style</th>
        <th scope="col">Skill</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="band : ${bands}">
        <td th:text="${band.bandName}">Band Name</td>
        <td th:text="${band.city}">City</td>
        <td th:text="${band.role.roleName}">Role Name</td>
        <td th:text="${band.style.styleName}">style Name</td>
        <td th:text="${band.skill.level}">Level</td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/band(id=${band.id})}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/band/delete(id=${band.id})}">Remove</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Why are you using a pseudo element for this?

Comment: @HaldenCollier 

On the example that I saw, it worked fine. But when I tried it out on my code, it wasnt working. The pseudeo element ":before" is suppose to always show what is before the value. In this case the header/titels (Band Name, City, Role, Style, Skill)

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or Codepen?

Answer (score 0):

I got the help of a friend to answer this question
The code that had to be changed is:

```
 HTML:
 <td data-label="Band Name"th:text="${band.bandName}">Band Name</td>
```

And

```
 CSS:
 .table td::before{
  content: attr(data-label);
```